# Saving currently running redmine docker changes to reuse

Tags: ubuntu, docker, redmine

I´m new to docker and already running a production redmine docker that I´ve made changes to (mostly js,css and html to customizing it a bit).
I´m quite happy with the way it looks now but, due to my lack of knowledge when I started it, I missed some things that I want to add now, such as mail server and point my whole app to a subdomain rather than the main that is currently on.
Here are my questions:

I first ran the image with:

```
docker run -p 80:80 --name=redmine --rm --link=mysql-redmine:mysql /
    --volume=/srv/docker/redmine/redmine:/home/redmine/data sameersbn/redmine:3.4.2
```

And all I have done since then is `docker restart` to see HTML changes, but I´m not confident with rerunning it as It would not save those changes, am I right?

Are env variables necessary every time I run it, or there is a way to save them in my image to simply run the image always at the same ports and MySQL DB? I´ve taken a look at the running docker files and database.yml has the correct config passed during the first run but I don´t really know if they are saved or not for the next run.

And last one: I know I can commit this image to a custom one to save some of the changes, but again, I don´t really know which of those are and which are not saved. ¿Are envs on run saved on commit?

Hope you can help, documentation is not really clear on this and not really extensive, and workarounds are often based on very specific cases that don´t really answer all my questions.

Also, I know about Docker files but the same doubts about it and the run command.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes you make to a container such as: adding new packages like a email server, adding vi / nano or other packages **would not be persistent** which means each time you **stop** and **start** the container your changes would be **lost** and you would have to re-do it.

To make them persistent you would have to create a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#parser-directives) and in there you can specify the **FROM** directive such as:

```
FROM "sameersbn/redmine:3.4.2"
```

and inside this Dockerfile you would have to specify your additional packages such as:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install xyz
```

Which will install the required package(s)

Then you would have to build the images:

```
docker build -t my_new_image:1.0.0 .
```

Which will create a new image with the desired packages installed, so you wouldn't lose them.

Also, you could add your HTML files by using the **COPY** or **ADD** commands or as you are doing currently using **VOLUMES**

Lastly, to do have to always pass the ENV variables each time a good solution would be using a [docker-compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#use--f-to-specify-name-and-path-of-one-or-more-compose-files) which will contain everything to run the container.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Useful info, thanks, i´ll use the docker-composer file part. I´m already adding those files via docker cp command to the volume, that I think is what  You are saying with COPY or ADD, am I right?

Comment: @RodrigoGross Exactly, when you pass --volume that mounts your local files to the container and what you write inside the container in that volume will be kept even though you stop & remove the container and vice versa. In your Dockerfile *COPY* will copy the local files into the container, however, if your container writes the files during the life time of the container when you stop and remove the container those files would be lost

Comment: Aaaaand that's exactly what I wanted to hear! Thanks mate! That solves most of my doubts. I will try it with several options when assured none of my users are awake and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve changes to HTML files and environment variables, it's best to create a new image using a Dockerfile.

```
FROM sameersbn/redmine:3.4.2
COPY modified.html /path/to/original.html
ENV SOME_VARIABLE=value
```

Then build image `docker build -t local/redmine:3.4.2 .` and run it `docker run ... local/redmine:3.4.2`.

Another solution would be to run the original image and overwrite html file using a volume: `docker run ... -v /path/to/modified.html:/path/to/original.html sameersbn/redmine:3.4.2`.

In my opinion the latter is better solution, unless you need to distribute the image with edited html content. If you find writing long commands cumbersome, you can put it to simple script or preferably write a `docker-compose.yml` file and run `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified that I´m already using "docker cp" to send those files to the volume, so the thing how to make persistent those files that I´ve already sent, maybe saving my modified volume as my to-use image? Will my saved image contain those changes? Thanks for asking!